# "If" statement condition always Untrue

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, excel-2010

The CONDITION of the "If" statement hereunder is always untrue (that is to say that the program never goes to FIN:).

```
If CONDITION Then
GoTo FIN
Else
End If
```

I have tried the following conditions:

```
Bm=1
Bm=1.0
Bm = CDbl(1)
Bm<=1
Bm <= CDbl(1)
Bm <= 1.0
Bm=Bmin
```

Bm and Bmin are both declarated as Double:
[Bm and Bmin declarations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHgpA.png)
Bm and Bmin are well egal to 1 when the condition is tested
[Variables values when the condition is tested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvyyE.png)

I just want the program to exit if the variable Bm = 1

I have tried also these conditions in a previous Do while loop as follow:

```
Do While condition1 And Bm <> 1
```

It doesn't work neither.

Any idea?

Comment: Would help to show a complete code (not as pictures) which replicates the problem you're seeing.

Comment: `Dim Bm As Double: 
Bm = 1: 
If Bm = 1 Then MsgBox "Equal"` works for me

Comment: If the issue is related to VBA's number precision, you may consider using an absolute value condition. `If Abs(Bm - 1) < 10^ - 5 Then`

Comment: have you tried stepping through the code and checking the locals window to make sure that Bm = 1 at the point the if statement is considered?

Comment: Thank you to all for your quick answers :) It helped me not to feel alone in this wired issue!

Comment: Taller's idea makes me solve the problem. The condition working for me is Bm<1.1 .

Comment: So there is a display issue in the VBA GUI. As you can see in the post the variables Bm and Bmin values are 1 in the Local variables window at the moment of the condition test. In fact this is not the case deeper...

Comment: Maybe some tips about Local variables display format?